# Assign Data Accordingly to New Column and Merge Duplicate Data according to value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working as a animator, programming is still very new to me but previously my boss assigned a job to me by merging 2 different xls files into one. I managed to research some code over here and use VBA code copy and paste the data according to the new workbook header.

For example here's  the file

```
  Username  Name  Date  Image   Attempt  Date  Image   Status
    222      AA    Aug    No       1 
    182      BB    Mar   Yes       0
    100      CC    Aug    No       1
    787      DD    Mar   Yes       0
```

But now I'm having a trouble of moving the data below from another xls file. And merge them according to "Username" the "Name" header. Because it contain new column of data.

```
    Username  Name  Date   Image    Status  
    222        AA   2013    Color     good 
    182        BB   2011    B/W       bad
    100        CC   2011    B/W       bad
    669        EE   2013    Color     good
```

And I need to turn them into something like below

```
  Username  Name  Date  Image   Attempt  Date  Image   Status
    222      AA    Aug    No       1     2013   Color   good
    182      BB    Mar   Yes       0     2011   B/W     bad
    100      CC    Aug    No       1     2011   B/W     bad 
    787      DD    Mar   Yes       0     2013   Color   good 
    669      EE                          2013   Color   good
```

If any keyword or guide will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should bring over all data and add any that are not already in wb1 to the end of the file with empty space under date, image, and attempt.

```
Dim wb1, wb2 as Workbooks
Dim ws1, ws2 as Worksheets
Dim c3ll1, c3ll2, range1, range2 as Range

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Name1")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Name2")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("name")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("name")

lastrow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set range2 = ws2.Range("A2:A" & lastrow2)

For each c3ll2 in range2
    a = 0
    lastrow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set range1 = ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastrow1)
    activerow2 = c3ll2.Row

    For each c3ll1 in range1
        If c3ll1.Value = c3ll2.Value then
            activerow1 = c3ll1.Row
            ws1.Cells(activerow1, 6) = ws2.Cells(activerow2, 3)
            ws1.Cells(activerow1, 7) = ws2.Cells(activerow2, 4)
            ws1.Cells(activerow1, 8) = ws2.Cells(activerow2, 5)
            a = 1                                                   'Username is found
        End if
    Next c3ll1

    If a = 0 then                       'If Username is not found print at end
        ws1.Cells(lastrow1 + 1, 1) = ws2.Cells(activerow2, 1)
        ws1.Cells(lastrow1 + 1, 2) = ws2.Cells(activerow2, 2)
        ws1.Cells(lastrow1 + 1, 6) = ws2.Cells(activerow2, 3)
        ws1.Cells(lastrow1 + 1, 7) = ws2.Cells(activerow2, 4)
        ws1.Cells(lastrow1 + 1, 8) = ws2.Cells(activerow2, 5)
    End If
Next c3ll2
```

Comment: I already open the workbook2, but when i run F8. It show the code Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("name")<---- Method or Data Member not found.

Comment: Did you change "name" to the name of your worksheet?

Comment: Ya i did, i have a code which open a new workbook.So total i have two workbooks. But each sheets in different workbook.

Comment: It would be easier if you just open a new workbook and save it so you know the name of it and you can set that in the code.  Unless this is an automated process that you will be doing all of the time.